Chrome extension to hide elements based on keywords/text
I am looking for a Chrome extension that can hide elements based on the text/keywords that this element contains.
If a certain keyword or phrase was found, the parent element should be hidden or removed.
Any recommendations?

What does "contained" mean? In the body? Or any property? And I assume only the closest children? This question severl lacks details.

Is it better now?
